# How to mark all the packets coming from a device?

Tags: iptables

I create a tun device using `ip tuntap add dev tun0 mode tun`, then I want to set mark to all the packets coming from tun0 using `iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j MARK --set-mark 1`. But when I check matched rules using `iptables -t mangle -nvL`, zero packets were matched. Can somebody help me with this?

Actually I have tried other filters and got nothing. Does this have something to do with tun0 configuration?

Comment: Are you sure any packets were egress to this `tun0` interface?

Answer (score 1):

`-o tun0` is an **output** device filter, so your mangle rule matches packets that leave the system via `tun0`. To mark packets that are coming in from `tun0`, use `-i tun0`, and probably better do it in the `PREROUTING` chain.

Also notice packet marks don't automatically apply to reply packets; this rule will only ever mark packets of one unidirectional flow (a bidirectional connection has two flows). To mark reply packets use a *connection mark* module. If you need packet marks, for instance, for policy routing, you can copy connection mark to a packet mark, there is a specific action for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer cleared all my confusion.  All the direction-related concepts like INPUT, OUTPUT, PREROUTING, POSTROUTING, are based on the system, not interfaces.